# State value not incrementing through dispatching action to redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

Via a button im trying to increment the score value that is dispatched through an action but upon clicking the button i get the error objects are not valid as a react child. My state only has 1 property right now score and im trying to update that value. Im using redux's configure store because create store is depercated. App is being wrapped in a Provider tag as per redux instructions for scope of use of the store. Im not sure where Im going wrong.

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

scoreDisplay.js

```
const ScoreDisplay = () => {

    const score = useSelector((state) => state.score)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const updateScore = () => {
        dispatch({type: 'update_score'})
    }

    return(
        <>
        <h1>Score</h1>
        <div>{score}</div>
        <button onClick={updateScore}>Update Score</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default ScoreDisplay;
```

STORE: index.js

```
const scoreReducer = (state = { score : 0 }, action) => {
    if(action.type == "update_score"){
        return { score : state.score + 1}
        
    }
    return state.score;
}

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        score: scoreReducer
    }
    
});

export default store;
```

Comment: Are you using redux toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting your full reducer as `state.score` here, so the incremented value is `state.score.score` in the end.

Generally, it seems as if you are learning Redux right now, and the reason that `createStore` is deprecated is that you should not be writing any of this by hand, but use the official Redux Toolkit for all of that code.

I would highly recommend you follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) as right now you are starting to learn practices that are outdated by years and will lead to you writing four times the amount of code you would need with modern Redux (with a much higher bug potential as well).

Also see [Why Redux Toolkit Is Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today)

Comment: Thank you, yes im learning. I will try this when i resolve these webpack required errors : / 
I appreciate the resources

Comment: Has `useSelector((state) => state.score.score)` resolved your problem now?